# close a Lotus Notes's session with JAVA

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am in the course of writing a Java program that uses Notes.jar whose goal to connect to a Domino server.
In this sense I started with instantiated a Session object and create a NotesSession.
I need to know, if I can close this session at the end of the programm for reasons 
of security.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [Link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/e17ff66fd197f0428525729f002fbc10?OpenDocument) will help you.

From the Link:
The way to close a remote session is to call `session.recycle()` to release resources on the server. To close the TCP-Connection is to do:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(remote args);
session.getUsername();
session.recycle();
session = null;
```

Nullifying the session should release the TCP connection at some point.

Comment: and does it fix your problem ?

Comment: my probleme is that  i open a lotus session with java and then i call a c# com object that it open also  the same lotus session so i have some probleme.

then, i think that if i close the session in java befor calling the c# com object ,it will solve the issue .But even the object's recycling well work , the principal issue dosen't resolved..

Comment: the  generated error is :

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): Le serveur a généré une exception. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Comment: must the two session be the same ?

Comment: when i run the java class that use the Com object it work very well.
But if i run all the java project  it generate an error at the level of this class..

Comment: sorry but i did not understand your whole problem without seeing the code.